# Sharepoint search Everything, People, Conversations not working

Tags: search, search-results

I have SharePoint search up and running on my site. It is working but only if I search this site. If i try to search Everything, People or Conversations it sends me to a "The page you're looking for doesn't exist".

I have configured Managed Metadata, Search, User Profile Application services.

sps3://mysite.com is added to the search service content source

I have followed this guide to try to make the people search working:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311.aspx

But I think it is odd that none of them are working... Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Search Settings are invalid - in particular the redirect to the Search Center. 
Verify that you have /Pages appended in the Search Center Url. Verify that the Pages it redirects you to, exists (e.g. results.aspx) - they are in the Pages library.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mFWc.png